# Testing environment configuration: Android + JUnit 5 + Mockito + Spek + Kotlin

Tags: android, junit, mockito, junit5, spek

I'm having hard time with configuration of a testing environment based on JUnit Jupiter (5). I have two different errors there:

```
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'spek' failed to discover tests
org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Could not load class with name...

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher.execute(Lorg/junit/platform/launcher/LauncherDiscoveryRequest;)V
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:61)...
```

And the configuration goes as follows.

Main `build.gradle`:

```
    apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-3'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta5'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.0"
        classpath "de.mannodermaus.gradle.plugins:android-junit5:1.0.0"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/spek" }
    }
}


junitPlatform {
    filters {
        engines {
            include 'spek'
        }
    }
}
```

Module `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'de.mannodermaus.android-junit5'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    ...

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'

    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.spek:spek-api:1.1.4'
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.spek:spek-junit-platform-engine:1.1.4'

    testImplementation junit5()
//    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.0' not needed when using the one above
    testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.0.0'

    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.47'
    testImplementation 'com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin-kt1.1:1.5.0'
    testCompileOnly "de.mannodermaus.gradle.plugins:android-junit5-embedded-runtime:1.0.0"
}
```

This configuration is supposed to be based on https://github.com/aurae/android-junit5. But I also tried without it.

**Have anyone managed to find a working configuration of dependencies for these libraries?**

Comment: related. https://github.com/JetBrains/spek/issues/256

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48427771/4249825 you need the following in your build.gradle:

app's build.grale:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath "de.mannodermaus.gradle.plugins:android-junit5:1.0.30"  // latest atm
    }
}
```

module's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: "de.mannodermaus.android-junit5"

android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
        androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/androidTest/kotlin'
    }
}

project.ext {
    spekVersion = "1.1.5"  // latest atm
    mockitoKotlinVersion = "2.0.0-alpha02"  // latest atm
    kluentVersion = "1.34"  // latest atm
}

dependencies {
    ...
    //
    // TESTS
    testCompile "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:$mockitoKotlinVersion"
    testImplementation "org.amshove.kluent:kluent-android:$kluentVersion"
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.spek:spek-api:$spekVersion") {
        exclude group: "org.jetbrains.kotlin"
    }
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.spek:spek-junit-platform-engine:$spekVersion") {
        exclude group: "org.junit.platform"
        exclude group: "org.jetbrains.kotlin"
    }
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"

    testImplementation junit5.unitTests()
    // see https://github.com/mannodermaus/android-junit5#android-studio-workarounds
    testCompileOnly junit5.unitTestsRuntime()
}
```