# Android Studio + Spek integration

Tags: unit-testing, junit, kotlin, android-studio-3.0, spek

I'm trying to add Spek testing framework to my Android Studio project. Following the instructions [Here](http://spekframework.org/docs/latest/), I ended up adding the following to my module `build.gradle`:

```
testCompile 'org.jetbrains.spek:spek-api:1.1.5'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.0.0"
testRuntimeOnly 'org.jetbrains.spek:spek-junit-platform-engine:1.1.5'
```

Then I annotated my test with `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform::class)`

However, when I try to run the test, I get:
`org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Cannot create Launcher without at least one TestEngine; consider adding an engine implementation JAR to the classpath`

Any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(For future references)
To use Kotlin and Spek + JUnit5 in Android Studio you need the following:

In *project's* **build.gradle** you need to have:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.10'
    ext.JUnit5_version = '1.0.30'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "de.mannodermaus.gradle.plugins:android-junit5:$JUnit5_version"
    }
}
```

In *module's* **build.gradle** you need to have:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: "de.mannodermaus.android-junit5"

android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
        androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/androidTest/kotlin'
    }
}

project.ext {
    spekVersion = "1.1.5"
}

dependencies {
    ...
    //
    // TESTS
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.spek:spek-api:$spekVersion") {
        exclude group: "org.jetbrains.kotlin"
    }
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.spek:spek-junit-platform-engine:$spekVersion") {
        exclude group: "org.junit.platform"
        exclude group: "org.jetbrains.kotlin"
    }
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"

    testImplementation junit5.unitTests()
    // see https://github.com/mannodermaus/android-junit5#android-studio-workarounds
    testCompileOnly junit5.unitTestsRuntime()
}
```

**Simple Spek test**

```
class ExampleSpekTest : Spek({
    val x = 2
    val y = 3

    given("x = $x and y = $y") {
        val sum = x + y

        it("should be that x + y = 5") {
           Assert.assertEquals(5, sum)
        }

        it("should be that x - y = -1") {
            val subtract = x - y
            Assert.assertEquals(-1, subtract)
        }
    }
})
```

See
- official documentation http://spekframework.org/
- official plugin for running specs from the IDE https://github.com/raniejade/spek-idea-plugin
- Tests using Spek Framework - BDD Style vs JUnit Style https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asDZ_7ZUiX4
- Simple Android configuration of Spek and JUnit5 https://gist.github.com/Mugurell/088daf42a4d60240ba6993681e0537a5

Comment: Do you have any idea how to write these two lines in the Kotlin DSL?`testImplementation junit5.unitTests()` `testCompileOnly junit5.unitTestsRuntime()`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it doesn't work well... I ended up using [kotlintest](https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest) which is much easier to integrate